# i want relative path for a file in java

Tags: java

I am new to java. I want to read a properties file in java. But i have my properties file in a different path in the same project.

I don't want to hard-code it. I want try with dynamic path.
Here is my code,

```
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     try{
        File file = new File("myFile.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);

        properties.load(fileInput);

     }catch(Exception ex)
     {
         System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
```

my file is in the folder, `webapp/txt/myFile.properties`.

Can any one help me in solving this issue?.

Comment: As far as I can remember, when coded like that, it is usually looking in the folder with the WAR or JAR for the property file.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is split the absolute path to you file in two parts

1. Path till your project folder
2. path from you project folder onwards (Relative path)

You can tread these two properties in your application and concatenate and get the absolute path of the file. The relative path remains configurable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Properties loadDBProperties() {
    InputStream dbPropInputStream = null;
    dbPropInputStream = DbConnection.class
            .getResourceAsStream("MyFile.properties");
    dbProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        dbProperties.load(dbPropInputStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dbProperties;
}
```

you can call this method from

```
dbProperties = loadDBProperties();
String dbName = dbProperties.getProperty("db.schema");//you can read your line form here of properties file
```

Answer (score 0):

if its under `webapp/txt.myFile.properties` and webapp is the public web space, then you need to read it using absolute URL

```
getServletContext().getRealpath("/txt/myFile.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Properties prop=new Properties();
  InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/txt/myFile.properties");
  prop.load(input);
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty(<PROPERTY>));
```