# Reading properties file from the root of Web Application

Tags: java, properties

I have to read properties file "MyProperty.properties" from "ReadProp.java" class given my the following directory structure of my "war" file I am going to deploy.

```
MyApp.war
|
----MyProps
|       |--MyProperty.properties
|---WEB-INF
|        |--classes
|             |---ReadProp.java
```

I am going to deploy this "war" file in "Sun portal server".
But I should not change any of this directory structure because of the requirement specification.

what is the best way to read the property file "MyProperty.properties" 
from "ReadProp.java" class ?

Comment: follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457041/i-want-relative-path-for-a-file-in-java/12457133#12457133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got Answer

```
 String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/MyProps/MyProperty.properties");
        System.out.println("path: " + path);

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String name= prop.getProperty("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this

```
ReadProp.class.getResourceAsStream("MyProps/MyProperty.properties");
```

The Myprops should be in server classpath.

Ideal way doing this things is keep this `Myprops`  in  WEB-INF/classes directory.

Comment: but my requirement is like this only. we cant change the requirement

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to place your file under `src/resources/MyProperty.properties`. It will end up under `classes` inside your `.war`. Still better to use `/src/main` and `/src/test`, then if a resource, such as `.properties` file, is required by `main`, keep that in `src/main/resources/MyProperty.properties`.